# Gratis Audio Visualization and Analysis Software

Tags: windows, gratis, audio, music

I am not certain that I will be able to describe this correctly, but I am in need of a gratis Audio Visualization software. Something that is able to display frequency strength in multiple display types (Bars, Waveform, Spectrum).

Requirements:

- Windows 10 Compatible
- Gratis (Open source would be a plus)
- Customizable/Able to create skins for the output (As well as custom resolutions for the skins)
- Variable accuracy/number of frequency bands that are analyzed
- Multiple outputs for multiple audio tracks in a file
- Support for multiple file types (Specifically MIDI and FLAC)

Nice to Have:

- Able to pass a system audio device to be analyzed
- EQ with a variable amount of frequency bands
- API to analyze the audio
- Debug/Analysis output and playback (Realtime scrubbing, logging frequency distribution for a specific portion of an audio clip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort of analysis & customisation that you are looking for are available with the combination of [python](https://www.python.org/), and [PyAudioAnalysis](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis) *which uses a combination of [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)/[SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/) & [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)*, you can also take a look at [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/python/dashboard/), [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/), etc. for the actual visualisation.

This [paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0144610) gives some examples of it's use as does the [wiki](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/wiki).

- Windows 10, *and earlier plus OS-X/Linux/*
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Multiple file types: Already supports a few formats but [PySoundFile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySoundFile/) is your friend. For MIDI, (which is not actually a **sound** file), you would need to use one of the many python packages that can convert midi to audio.
- High level of customisation.

You should also take a look at the tools listed on [PythonInMusic](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic#Audio_Analysis) for Audion Analysis. One such option is [Friture](http://friture.org/):
[image]

For a less flexible, *but ready rolled*, solution you might like to take a look at [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/).
[image]